# How to show custom Icon on Contact with no Image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-contacts

I want to show a list of Contacts with their Image on left, I am able to achieve this with below code, But I want to know how can I show a custom Icon on left If there is no Image set for that Contact?

I've my Custom icon in drawables, named as "my_icon".

The Fragment Where I'm Showing Contact List;

```
    public class FragmentContacts extends Fragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    ImageView imageView;
    private ListView lv_ContactList;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    private static final String DISPLAY_NAME = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB                         
    ? ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

    private static final String[] contactsColumns = {    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,         
    ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI    };
    private final String contactsFilter = "(" +ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER+ "='1') AND 
    (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "='1')";
    private final String contactsSortOrder = DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    private final static String[] listDisplayColumns = { DISPLAY_NAME, 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI   };
    private final static int[] listDataViewIDs = { R.id.contact_name, R.id.imgContact };

    String[] mSelectionArgs;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_contacts, null);
    lv_ContactList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_ContactList);
    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    mCursorAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity(), R.layout.list_row_contact, null,         
    listDisplayColumns, listDataViewIDs, 0);
    lv_ContactList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args ) {
    if(mSelectionArgs == null)
        return new CursorLoader( getActivity(), ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,         
     contactsColumns, contactsFilter, null, contactsSortOrder );
    else
        return new CursorLoader( getActivity(), ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,         
     contactsColumns, contactsFilter + " AND (" + DISPLAY_NAME+" LIKE ?)", mSelectionArgs, 
      contactsSortOrder );
       }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data ) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset( Loader<Cursor> loader ) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out,
Just used `android:background="@drawable/my_icon"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/my_icon"` and it showed it's magic

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/my_icon"
android:layout_width="35dip"
android:background="@drawable/chaticon"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="5dip" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Import your custom image into the drawables.
If the uri of the contact photo does not exist then upload the custom image

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom image to the drawables. Once you have it there go to your layout and in the ImageView, you can set it as src your image. The image will be displayed until you set another image.

In this example ImageView I used the "@drawable/icondummy" as the image when is loading or empty.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageUserIconHome"
    android:src="@drawable/icondummy"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp" />
```

Comment: Please add code as Text, instead of images, it is easier for people to verify your answer that way.

Comment: @UtaibaNaqshbandi did you get an error? or just still being empty?